# Using "WHERE" and "AND" in php

Tags: php, where-clause

Anybody know why the this isn't working:

```
$no = $_GET['no'];
$findinterval = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM intervals ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($findinterval);
$id = $result['id'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$create_log = mysql_query("INSERT INTO visitors VALUES ('','$ip','$date','$no','$id')");
```

The above works fine on insertion.

```
$uniquecheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE no = '$no' AND interval = '$id' AND ip = '$ip'");`
```

`var_dump` is giving `bool(false)`.

As the accepted answer verifies, the question was not vague at all.  Nevertheless -4 it is.

Comment: 1) how are you getting your variables? Post the code how they are set. -- 2) have you got correct database connection information (`mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db`) -- 3) does your table/columns exist.

Comment: Yes you should show us how you are getting the variables because, the query ( or half of it) seems to be fine

Comment: The variables i set worked fine when i used them to insert into a tb.  Will they need redefining perhaps for this later query?

Comment: We can't possibly tell if you don't show the code.

Comment: @Roy saying one thing is not showing. You need to give the information we are asking for in order to even make an attempt to help you -- Hence your question is on -4..

Comment: @Roy more importantly. what are you using this query to do? because using `mysql_query` is one thing; actually getting results/using it in PHP is a different story.

Comment: Supplied above now.  Thanks...

Comment: @Roy what are you going to use this query for..? get information from an array and use it somewhere else? `mysql_fetch_array` or use it as an object? `mysql_fetch_asoc` -- get the number of rows? `mysql_num_rows` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interval` is a reserved word in mysql, so you need to put it in backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM visitors WHERE no = '$no' AND `interval` = '$id' AND ip = '$ip'
```

Apart from that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you should move to PDO / mysqli and prepared statements to close the sql injection hole you have now.

Comment: And free your results when you're done!  `mysql_free_result($result);`

Comment: @bobthyasian That's just as deprecated as the rest :-)

Comment: @jeroen Well he's using `mysql_*` might as well use it correctly.